# Will a diode change how my IC works?

Tags: voltage, diodes, integrated-circuit

If I have an IC, any IC, with a V+ and a V- that has a minimum voltage requirement of 3V to operate. Say I supply that exact 3V, but I want to add a silicon diode to the V- to prevent a reverse voltage from damaging the IC. Would it mean that I now have to compensate my voltage supply to accommodate the 3V drop and the 0.7V drop? Or would the diode have no effect to my circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd have to allow for the 0.7 V drop but the voltage drop will vary with the current drawn.

Most of us would probably put the diode in the positive supply and keep battery negative as ground. This simplifies connecting up peripherals, etc., and is the normal way of doing things.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvJLmj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) doesn't share ground with the battery negative as would be conventional. (b) does and has an inherent "neatness".*

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that there are better, if a few cents more expensive, ways to prevent a backwards connection that don't drop half a volt in a diode. With a 3V system, the 400~500mV drop of a schottky diode is pretty significant and a FET based approach would probably be preferred.

Comment: So if I place the diode in the positive supply, would it still allow for me to protect the IC from reverse voltage?

Comment: It's a series circuit so order of components doesn't matter. With (a) or (b) you will have the same protection but as Hearth points out this is not the best way to provide the protection.

Comment: @Forever: Thanks for accepting my answer but I recommend that you wait a day or so to let others answer and then accept the best one. Voting too early dissuades others from answering and you might miss some good tricks and learnings.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the tip and the help.